# .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET 5 Migration with Galasoft MVVMLight Library

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, .net-5

We are migrating our WPF application to .NET 5.

Today we faced some problems with **Galasoft Library named MVVMLight**. We saw that there are no updates for .NET Standard. We cannot use a.e. `EventToCommand` class.

Do you know which options could we manage?

Answer (score 3):

The regular [MVVMLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) and [MVVMLightLibs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs/) NuGet packages are incompatible with .NET 5, they are only compatible with .NET Framwork and a few other platforms. However, there are dedicated packages for .NET Standard 1.0 which will work for .NET 5, too.

- [MVVMLightStd10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightStd10/)
- [MVVMLightLibsStd10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibsStd10/)

You can read more about these versions on the offical MVVMLight web page [here](http://www.mvvmlight.net/std10). Please be aware, that this version does not support the `IServiceProvider` interface.

> One particular interface, IServiceProvider, which is used by the SimpleIoc component, is not available in .NET Standard 1.0. [...] the ServiceLocator class is not available anymore.

This affects SimpleIoC, which you have to get through the static `SimpleIoc.Default` member instead.

```
// OLD var nav = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
// NEW
var nav = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
```

---

An alternative is to use the the [*XamlBehaviors for WPF*](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf) if you are searching for a repacement for `EventToCommand`. This is a library by Microsoft that replaces the legacy Blend behaviors.

You can install the NuGet package [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](http://Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf), which is compatible with .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET 5. The equivalent to `EventToCommand` there is [`InvokeCommandAction`](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors/InvokeCommandAction.cs).